# Java: object declaration

Tags: java, object, initialization

When declaring an object in Java:

```
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process lsProc = rt.exec("who -q");
InputStream in = lsProc.getInputStream();
```

Why is `lsproc` not declared this way -> `Process lsproc = new Process`?
How can an object `lsproc` hold the value of another function?

Comment: That´s what the returntype of a method is there for...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method `rt.exec("who -q")` can return a reference to an instance of type `Process`. It might create that instance itself by calling `new Process (..)` (or actually, since `Process` is an abstract class, by creating an instance of a sub-class of `Process`), or it may retrieve it from elsewhere.

Following the chain of calls of the `Runtime.exec(String)` method leads to this call :

```
    return new ProcessBuilder(cmdarray)
        .environment(envp)
        .directory(dir)
        .start();
```

The `start` method calls `ProcessImpl.start` which actually creates the `Process` instance.

Comment: but when i try to do this: Process lsproc = new Process why do I get an error?

Comment: @user5444075 That's because you cannot instantiate an abstract class. Read my answer fully.

Comment: @user5444075 Because `Process` is an abstract class, so it can't be instantiated. The actual class being instantiated is `ProcessImpl`.

Comment: so this means i have to indirectly initialize the object lsproc am i right?

Comment: @user5444075 No. It's a direct way. You are just getting initialized in some other method which returns your actual object

Comment: @user5444075 If by indirectly you mean that you don't invoke the constructor explicitly then you are right. `ProcessImpl`'s constructor is private, so you can't invoke it directly.

Comment: Okay, but another question arises, how will I know that the method is returning the same value? Do i need to do this every time I have to instantiate an object of class Process

Comment: @user5444075 Every time you which to execute a command in a separate process you should call the `exec` method. Instantiating the object is not the goal here. The goal is to execute a command (`who -q` in your code sample).

Comment: @Eran okay so cant we just type rt.exec("who -q"); and call it instead of Process lsProc = rt.exec("who -q");

Comment: Finally I can conclude that Process' objects cannot be instantiated because it is abstract. So, we have to instantiate it by calling another function which in turn returns new constructer. And turns out that after obtaining the object we can call functions of the classes anytime. Please correct me if I am wrong. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2):

```
 Process lsProc = rt.exec("who -q");
```

That line alone means,

That means the method `exec` of `Runtime` Class returning an instance `IsProc` of type `Process`.

Look at the [`source code of exec method`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/Runtime.java#Runtime.exec%28java.lang.String%5B%5D%2Cjava.lang.String%5B%5D%2Cjava.io.File%29)

```
public Process exec(String[] cmdarray, String[] envp, File dir)
609        throws IOException {
610        return new ProcessBuilder(cmdarray)
611            .environment(envp)
612            .directory(dir)
613            .start();
614    }
```

It's returning the instance of `ProcessBuilder` which is of type `Process`, that means Process is an abstract class and `ProcessBuilder` is it's concrete class.

Now you might encounter a question that how

```
Process pro = new ProcessBuilder(..);
```

is valid, that routes you to read about Polymorphism.

Comment: Process is not an interface. It's an abstract class.

Answer (score 0):

Because it returns a `Process`. See [here #exec(java.lang.String)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec(java.lang.String))